# Удалить нельзя восстановить (прочитать)

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, удаление-вопросов, удаление-ответов

Есть функционал "Удалить вопрос", "Удалить комментарий", "Удалить ответ".

Вопрос: если эти, так называемые, "удалённые" объекты видны модераторам и лицам с необходимым количество репутации, то какое же это удаление?

Почему бы не перестать вводить в заблуждение пользователей, называя действия не своими именами? Ну или хотя бы их ЯВНО информировать о том, что ничто, сказанное ими, не будет удалено в принципе.

Comment: Ну для <10k их нет, смекаешь?

Comment: `какое же это удаление?` Мягкое)

Comment: А ещё, вспоминается человекайпадоножка... Нужно читать соглашения)

Comment: Почему удаление файла в корзину названо своим именем, а удаление вопроса - нет?

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что когда удаляете письмо в почтовом ящике, то оно не удаляется? Точно также как ваши файлы в Dropbox и т.п.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну, к слову, из корзины восстановить файл можно. Так что, тоже мягкое удаление.

Comment: Хотя, может "удалить" стоит заменить на "скрыть", например.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну так я именно поэтому такую аналогию и привёл - в обоих случаях нет бесследного исчезновения и восстановить можно. Но при этом никто не спорит, что удаление в корзину называется удалением, а не скрытием (тем более, скрытие означает совсем другое). PS: Модераторы не могут восстановить комментарии, удалённые обычными пользователями.

Comment: @Qwertiy в случае с корзиной это видите только вы. Я так понимаю, посыл автора вопроса больше в том, что он вроде как удалил/скрыл, но **другие** юзеры всё равно могут видеть.

Comment: Кстати, модераторы могут удалить часть ответа или вопроса насовсем, с потерей истории. Но эта фича используется только для удаления данных, которые попали в публичный доступ по ошибке (например, имен и паролей), и требует участия как минимум двух модераторов.

Comment: Всё, что однажды попало в интернет. остаётся в нём навсегда, воот :)

Comment: Скажу больше, термин совершенно верен в текущем виде - **у-далить** (перенести в даль), вовсе **не является уничтожением**.

Comment: @Kromster да вы что, а в какую же "даль" переносятся буквы, когда я нажимаю клавиши Delete или Backspace?)

Comment: @edem ровно в ту, из которой они возвращаются по Ctrl+Z. Вы спросили про термин - термин *удаление* вполне точно отражает суть. Механизм (реализация) удаления (и его ограничения.особенности) естественно может работать по разному.

Comment: @Kromster дело не в реализации и не в Ctrl+Z (с таким же успехом я бы мог и напечатать их заново), а в том, КТО их может вызвать из "небытия", если же куча других людей, кроме самого автора, то это немного не то.

Comment: Дайте определение слову "куча", десять человек из пары сотен тысяч? )

Comment: @Kromster этими десяти может стать любой из этой пары сотни тысяч. Предлагаю на этом закончить. Суть предложения описана в самом вопросе. Добавить тут нечего.

Answer (score 6):

Модераторы для своей работы по регулированию жизни сайта должны иметь доступ к большему количеству информации нежели обычные пользователи. Представьте, кто-то нецензурно обругал кого-то, этот кто-то получил уведомление, прочитал, настроение испортилось. А хулиган взял и удалил своё сообщение сразу. Если бы оно пропало бесследно, он мог бы уйти от ответственности, именно поэтому все действия достаточно подробно журналируются и доступны модераторам для обеспечения дальнейшего правосудия.

Участники с высокой репутацией могут видеть удаленные вопросы и ответы так же как и ромбоносные модераторы. (собственно привилегия так и называется ["инструменты модератора"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)). Но комментарии, которые были удалены, таким пользователям не видны. Возможность видеть удаленные сообщения — одна из причин, по которой участники стремятся набрать 10к репутации. То есть это, в частности, стимулирует участников задавать интересные вопросы и давать качественные ответы, а стало быть с каждым днем улучшать наполнение сайта. Здесь стоит заметить, что удаленные вопросы для таких участников видны только лишь по прямой ссылке, они недоступны для поиска и не видны в общем списке вопросов. Также имеет значение как был удален вопрос: самостоятельно автором, или путем голосования других участников или модератором. Самостоятельно удаленные вопросы не видны на [странице инструментов модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools).

О том, что термин "удаление" вполне подходит в данном случае уже много сказано в комментариях к вопросу. Но я приведу еще и другие аналогии: в некоторых базах данных записи фактически не удаляются при операции удаления, а всего лишь помечаются специальным флагом; файл, удаленный с диска, в общем случае не приводит к мгновенному и безвозвратному уничтожению информации, хранимой в этом файле, её всё еще можно извлечь, пока область хранения не перезаписана новыми данными.

Таким образом, удаление очень редко когда является действительно настоящим удалением без возможности какого бы то ни было восстановления. И в данном случае, для посетителей сайта извне удаленная информация действительно отсутствует: гугл не найдет её, а для многих отсутствие результата в поисковике вполне воспринимается как отсутствие информации. То есть удаление выполняет свою функцию — удаляет информацию с глаз широкой публики.

Пытаться впихнуть вместо термина "удаление" какие-то детали, рассказывающие о реальной сути дел — это просто перегружать интерфейс и мозги рядовых участников. То есть совершенно ненужное занятие. Текущий термин вполне отражает ситуацию на нужном уровне восприятия.

Comment: "Пытаться впихнуть вместо термина "удаление" какие-то детали, рассказывающие о реальной сути дел — это просто перегружать интерфейс и мозги рядовых участников." — вполне достаточно исправить текст всплывающий подсказки для ссылок (кнопок) с удалением, добавив ". Удалённые вопросы могут видеть такие-то и такие-то".

Comment: Как вам последняя правка? "журналируются". Такого слова в русском, так-то, тоже нет )

Comment: @Suvitruf почему нет, если есть? Вспомнить хотя бы журналируемые ФС.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ никогда не встречал до этого упоминания этого слова)

Comment: @Suvitruf every day for us something new (c) Metallica

Comment: вместо слова «удалить» можно было бы честно сказать «скрыть», а в подсказке детали упомянуть.

Comment: @jfs тут и так всё сложно по сравнению с другими сайтами, не надо грузить людям мозг дополнительно.